# Guitar Amp Power Supply Issues

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, vacuum-tube

I have a B-52 AT100 guitar amp on my bench (naturally, it wouldn't let me attach the .pdf I have of the schematic, so I had to attach it as two .jpegs. The schematic can easily be found online though, if the clarity is too poor). The original failure mode was screen resistors R106 and R105 had melted. Looking around the amp, I also found that R137 and D8 were burnt open. I replaced the failed resistors, measured them out of circuit, breifly turned the amp's standby on and measured the voltage drop across R137 to be 120VDC (100 mA thru it, and 12 W dissipation - which of course smoked it again)!

So my thought is something downstream of R137, like something being fed from B+3 or B+4, is drawing too much current. I can't seem to be able to nail it down though. So far I have:

1. Pulled all the tubes and checked them for shorts. None found.
2. Checked DC resistance from plate to ground on all tube sockets. The weird results were Tubes V4 and V11 (being fed from B+4, B+3 respectively), I read very low resistance, then it would jump up into the meg ohm range, then slowly climb back down into the 200 kOhm range.
3. Checked for shorts across the filter caps. None found.
4. The reverb tank is not connected, but it has not been connected for quite some time before the amp failed apparently.
5. When I checked the voltage across R137, I also measured B+1 real quick - 280VDC - which seems low. [image]
   [image]

Thoughts?

Comment: You're on the wrong site brother.  Guitar amplifiers are world unto themselves.  You don't want an Electrical Engineers analysis of one.  Try a guitar site like:   https://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?forums/amps-cabs-tech-corner-amplifier-cab-speakers.11/

Comment: You could try removing R140.  If the problem persists, the issue is downstream of it.  If it goes away, you've isolated the section where the trouble is.   Could be the filter caps have gone leaky.  Any caps showing signs of leaking or bulging???   Very common issue in modern tube amps (they use crappy capacitors)

Comment: VTC as this is about repair of consumer products, not electronic design.

Comment: @ Sparky 256 - As someone who is interested in electronic design, I disagree. I think this is a great opportunity to learn something. @Kyle B - There are a couple bulging caps. Can leakage go undetected without proof from a low resistance reading from a DMM across the caps?

Comment: @JE61   I say that because as somebody interested in electronics design AND somebody who repairs tube guitar amps regularly AND who has played guitar "quasi-professionally" for 40+years, I have a bit more insight than the average EE into them.  It's a hobby & passion to me.  The thing is, guitar amplifiers are possibly the only place in the whole of electronics where not only is distortion accepted, it is EMBRACED.   Guitar amps tend to operate in areas that are 
 somewhat "destructive" to the components - They sound best when they're just about to blow up (literally).

Comment: A knowledgable EE who really investigated how a guitar amp works would be appalled.  "Safe operating areas"   HA!   Nope.   We run the components right to the edge of meltdown.   Please know I'm not meaning to trivialize your attempts at learning.  I'm suggesting that a trained EE, without specific guitar amplifier experience, is not going to be in a good position to help you figure out "what's wrong".   For one thing, nobody teaches tube design in EE school anymore - You gotta find yourself a 70 year old EE to even have a chance at him/her knowing much of anything about them.

Comment: That's why I suggested "TheGearPage".   There are number of highly experienced amplifier techs (many of whom are EE's by training) who are very happy to share their insights.

Comment: Anyhow - Absolutely you should seek to replace the bulging capacitors.    Note your DMM is measuring leakage with about 1/2 Volt on the caps.  In practice, those caps have about 200V across them.  BIG DIFFERENCE!!!!!   If they are bulging, they are bad - No discussion needed - Case closed on that.  May or may not be your problem, but it's A problem for sure!!!!    You can PM me (same username) over at TheGearPage if you wanna chat more.

Comment: Thanks! I will certainly replace them. I never thought about there being only 1/2 V across them with the meter, I can see how that would be misleading. I will certainly check out TheGearPage forum, because I'm also a guitar player, and an aspiring amp tech.

Comment: @JE61 Nevertheless this is a repair question. While it is often useful to be an engineer to find faults and repair something, it is not granted that when something is finally repaired, a new design is done. That's why repair questions are considered off-topic here. They don't yield much engineering knowledge. And if they do, the true engineering problem is often concealed by all the tracking down of the faulty component.